# Как объяснить разные формы написания и согласования для слова каноэ?

Tags: морфология, раздельно-дефис

Какой вариант правильный или допускаются оба варианта?

1) **Два варианта согласования по роду** (средний и женский)

... блестящий поток, по которому **скользило каноэ** [Александр Проханов. (2001)]

Группа ловцов передвигалась **на специально сконструированной каноэ** [ Охота и охотничье хозяйство, 1969]

2) **Две формы написания** (раздельное и дефисное)

Троим конгрессменам пришлось пробираться к Капитолийскому холму по реке в спортивной **лодке каноэ**... [Василий Песков, (1977)]

Сидела Инка на диване, поджав ноги, словно диван ― **лодка-каноэ**...[Улья Нова. Инка (2004)]

Answer (score 1):

Каноэ среднего рода, поэтому вторая фраза уж точно ошибочна. Слово "лодка-каноэ" – сомнительный неологизм.

Comment: Так -то оно так, но  почему было выбрано нестандартное написание? 1) Группа ловцов передвигалась на специально сконструированной (лодке) каноэ. Может быть, здесь подразумевается слово  "лодка". Текст не общего характера, из специального журнала.  2)  Лодка-каноэ. А это сравнение в художественном тексте, произношение слитное, как при дефисном написании.  Может быть, это не сомнительный, а вполне уместный неологизм?

Comment: Раз неологизм – значит, к нему существующие правила неприменимы, и надо просто посмотреть, останется слово в языке или нет. Боюсь, что нет. Мало ли почему было выбрано нестандартное... В подобных случаях я стараюсь начинать с самых вероятных объяснений: например, автор не обратил внимания, а корректор недосмотрел.

Comment: Еще мне встретились лодки-байдарки. По-моему, это просто словосочетания. Лодка - определяемое слово, а каноэ, байдарка - приложения, конкретный вид лодки. Получается, что отношения в этом словосочетании неоднозначные: приложение и определяемое слово могут меняться местами. Лодка может быть приложением для каноэ (лодка каноэ), а может быть определяемым словом (лодка-каноэ).

Comment: @Ксения Справочник Розенталя по орфографии и пунктуации указывает, что дефис не пишется, "если в сочетании двух нарицательных существительных первое обозначает родовое понятие, а второе — видовое" (за исключением терминов, к которым это сочетание не относится), и это как раз наш случай. Обратите внимание, что тут вообще не обсуждается, кто из них приложение, а кто определяемое слово.

Comment: Лодка каноэ - это род + вид, обычное раздельное написание. Дефисное написание (лодка-каноэ, лодка-байдарка) переводит сочетание в терминологическое выражение (у Розенталя мышь-полевка, бабочка-капусница). В этом случае происходит слияние названий, произношение без паузы. Такое произношение  характерно  для термина,  а в приведенном примере удобно для сравнения.